# What does "modulo" mean in SMT?

Tags: terminology

Very simple question, for which I failed to find an explanation: what does "modulo" mean in the "Satisfiability Modulo Theories"?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_%28jargon%29 . Think of a theory as an equivalence relation between formulas given by provable equivalence.

Comment: Thanks. If you bother to write an answer and elaborate on "theory as equivalence relation", I can ack it.